# Is there any way to get samples in under each leaf of a decision tree in Sklearn ?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn, decision-trees

I have trained decision tree . I also have a graph of the tree (
[image]) . Now i want to see which samples (red circled ones ) are under which leafs . I am using sklearn's implantation .  Is there any way to get the samples under a leaf ? ?

Comment: Apply will only give you the leaf index, it doesn't explain how to get the array of y-values in that leaf

Answer (score 4):

Very good and analytical answers are provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45398737/is-there-any-way-to-get-samples-under-each-leaf-of-a-decision-tree) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506951/how-to-explore-a-decision-tree-built-using-scikit-learn).

For me, the easiest way would be to find the leaves where each sample belongs and then split the dataframe into clusters using `iloc`, to further analyse the clusters. This can be done using:

```
clf.apply(iris.data)
```

or

```
clf.predict(iris.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
Use the apply function on the fitted model.

See in [Documents](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.apply).

The mentioned leaf-index as the same as in the underlining _tree object(used for visualization).